# unable to create fastRP prediction pipeline due to error

Tags: neo4j, prediction, recommendation-engine, embedding

I've been trying to create an embedding for neo4j predictions for a steam database based on the [walkthrough](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/machine-learning/linkprediction-pipelines/config/), but every time I try to add properties consisting of a 3d embedding resulting from mapping genre to an embedding it fails with the error below.

query:

```
'''CALL gds.beta.pipeline.linkPrediction.train("Steam_Graph", {
                pipeline: 'steam_pipeline',
                modelName: 'steam_lp_model',
                metrics: ['AUCPR', 'OUT_OF_BAG_ERROR'],
                sourceNodeLabel: 'Person',
                targetNodeLabel: 'App',
                targetRelationshipType: 'owns',''' + '\n' + \
                f'randomSeed: {rseed}\n' + \
            '''}) YIELD modelInfo, modelSelectionStats
            RETURN modelInfo.modelName AS modelName, 
                   modelInfo.modelType AS modelType,
                   modelInfo.bestParameters AS winningModel,
                   modelInfo.metrics.AUCPR.train.avg AS avgTrainScore,
                   modelInfo.metrics.AUCPR.outerTrain AS outerTrainScore,
                   modelInfo.metrics.AUCPR.test AS testScore,
                   [cand IN modelSelectionStats.modelCandidates | cand.metrics.AUCPR.validation.avg] AS validationScores
            '''
```

error:

```
Query failed: {code: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed} {message: Failed to invoke procedure `gds.beta.pipeline.linkPrediction.train`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered NaN when combining the nodeProperties ['TSNE_x', 'TSNE_y', 'TSNE_z', 'embedding'] for the node pair (508, 1525) when computing the HADAMARD feature vector. Either define a default value if its a stored property or check the nodePropertyStep.}
```

What is strange about the error is I have defined the default value when creating the projection, so I don't know why this happens.

initial projection where I've loaded TSNE_blah values into all 'App' nodes:

```
'''CALL gds.graph.project(
            "Steam_Graph", //name of graph
            //there would be a list of the source/target/other nodes involved
            {
                App: {
                    properties: {
                        TSNE_x: {},
                        TSNE_y: {},
                        TSNE_z: {}\n''' + \
                    '''}
                }, Person: {
                    properties: {
                        TSNE_x: {defaultValue: 0},
                        TSNE_y: {defaultValue: 0},
                        TSNE_z: {defaultValue: 0}\n''' + \
                    '''}
                }, Publisher: {
                    properties: {
                        TSNE_x: {defaultValue: 0},
                        TSNE_y: {defaultValue: 0},
                        TSNE_z: {defaultValue: 0}\n''' + \
                    '''}
                }, Developer: {
                    properties: {
                        TSNE_x: {defaultValue: 0},
                        TSNE_y: {defaultValue: 0},
                        TSNE_z: {defaultValue: 0}\n''' + \
                    '''}
                }
            }, {
                owns: {orientation: "UNDIRECTED"}, 
                friend: {orientation: "UNDIRECTED"},
                Published_By: {orientation: "UNDIRECTED"},
                Developed_By: {orientation: "UNDIRECTED"}
            })'''
```

further calls from the notebook between generating the embedding and the prediction:

```
f'CALL gds.beta.pipeline.linkPrediction.addFeature("steam_pipeline", "hadamard", {{nodeProperties: ["embedding", "TSNE_x", "TSNE_y", "TSNE_z"]}})'
'CALL gds.beta.pipeline.linkPrediction.configureSplit("steam_pipeline", {testFraction: 0.25, trainFraction: 0.6})'
'CALL gds.alpha.pipeline.linkPrediction.addRandomForest("steam_pipeline", {numberOfDecisionTrees: 100}) YIELD parameterSpace'
'CALL gds.beta.pipeline.linkPrediction.train.estimate("Steam_Graph", {pipeline: "steam_pipeline", modelName: "steam_lp_model", targetRelationshipType: "owns"}) '
           'YIELD requiredMemory'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the only issue was removing TSNE_x: {defaultValue: 0} for all other nodes where it was not defined, the embedding seemed to work after that